# Attribute backgroundImage in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

how i can take an image from a file public to display?
I try this way but it did not work.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqA3.jpg)

Code :

```
 <div className="slider-item" style={{backgroundImage: 'url(images/bg_1.jpg)'}}>
      <div className="overlay" />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row no-gutters slider-text align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-md-12 ftco-animate text-center">
            <div className="text mb-5 pb-3">
              <h1 className="mb-3">Welcome To Furama</h1>
              <h2>Hotels &amp; Resorts</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a height and width for the div.

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
     <div 
      className="slider-item"
      style={{ 
        backgroundImage: 'url(/images/bg_1.jpg)' 
        height: '200px',
        width: '400px',
        backgroundSize: "cover"
      }}>
         Welcome To Furama
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

code: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kare-sw34gp?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:226-249)